# Nullable variable throws NullPointerException on get()

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

Here is some mistic error. I have such a code:

```
if (countryCode.value.code != US_CODE){
      doSomething()
}
```

"If" line throws Error: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.data.models.CountryCodeValue.getCode()' on a null object reference

"code" field is nullable, and I don't get why it happens

CountryCodeValue model:

```
data class CountryCodeValue(
    val code: String? = null,
    val name: String,
    var description: String
)
```

Comment: It doesn't complain about `code` being `null`, but `value`. So it seems `value` is defied as not nullable, but in fact it was null.

Comment: what is `value` here ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody value is CountryCodeValue model

Comment: so then it's entirely possible that your api isn't returning a CountryCodeValue ? i'm assuming this is from an api, have you check the json response ?

Comment: got it guys, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what your error line is saying:

```
Error: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'java.lang.String com.data.models.CountryCodeValue.getCode()' on a null object reference
```

It's saying you're trying to call `getCode()` on something that's null, instead of an actual `CountryCodeValue` object. `null` doesn't have that method, so it throws.

You need to use the null safety checks to handle potentially nullable stuff:

```
// gives you the property if thing is non-null, otherwise you get null
thing?.property
```

and you can chain those together:

```
// if any of these nullables are null, you get null instead of otherProperty
thing?.property?.otherProperty
```

`LiveData`s' `value`s can be null (e.g. when they're empty - I'm assuming that's what you're using here, but this applies whatever it is) so you have to null check what you get before you try accessing something on it

```
if (countryCode.value?.code != US_CODE){
      doSomething()
}
```

bear in mind this can also return null (that's your whole problem here!) so you probably want to handle that in your logic

Comment: I think the root cause here is not that OP didn't use safe operators, but that `value` is declared as not nullable. We should not use null checks for non-null values just because we expect them to be in fact nullable. It would show up as compiler warnings. And if the property would be properly marked as nullable, then safe operators would be enforced by the compiler.